# Find a range by to criteria

Tags: excel, vba

It have difficulties to combine the correct Excel functions to extract the correct data from my sheets.

The data sheet is structured like:

```
 |ABDEFGHIJKLMN
-+---------------------
1| OPQRST
2|7
3|7
4|8   x
5|8   x
6|9
```

In another table I have the criteria to be used for the search, e.g. "R" and "8", for which I would like to get the range (F4:F5, marked with "x", "x" is not the actual content). My goal would be to check if the resulting range contains any non-empty cells.

Any help?

I tried an approach using ADDRESS and MATCH, but it does not seem to work...

Comment: Look at a two-dimensional `INDEX/MATCH`. And whaddaya know when I search for that I find myself :) at http://yoursumbuddy.com/two-dimensional-index-match-formula-with-variable-length-lookup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is sorted ascending in column A, then this formula will work:

```
=COUNTA(INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH(L2,$A:$A,0),MATCH(L1,1:1,0)):INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH(L2,$A:$A,1),MATCH(L1,1:1,0)))
```

L1 holds the column label text, L2 holds the row label number. Applied in cell L4 and copied to the right for other value pairs.

[image]